# how to create external pipe for multiple table using single sqs?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-sqs, snowflake-schema

I need to load data into 2 table using snow pipe i.e. `table1,table2`

I have data in s3 `test_snow_pipe_exe` bucket `table1,table2` subfolders like below path:

```
 1) s3://test_snow_pipe_exe/table1/
 2) s3://test_snow_pipe_exe/table2/
```

so I have created stage by executing below code

```
create stage test_snow_stage_exe
  storage_integration = test_storageBucket
  url = 's3://test_snow_pipe_exe/'
  file_format = CSV_Format;
```

now I want to create 2 pipes with single sqs for 2 tables.

how to create 2 pipes with single sqs for 2 tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 pipes using same SQS notification to load data into two different tables.
You can also have single stage shared by multiple pipes that each write to distinct tables, and only one SQS notification.